# Sequelize relation with WHERE IN ("ARRAY")

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible to define a relationships in sequelize where multiple foreign keys are stored as an array in one field. Basically a belongsToMany but instead of an relation table all ids are stored comma separated in one field. Query would be with `WHERE IN('1,5,7')`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it, but definitely without foreign key constraints - there is no possibility of storing array of foreign keys. You can however create a column which will be an array of integers representing IDs of associated table. Then you just need to create some `instanceMethods` for retrieving and setting the array values (remember that the `ARRAY` type is only available in PostgreSQL).

I do not recommend this solution due to the fact that it does not ensure data consistency. Let's consider an example - user belongs to many categories with ids 1, 2 and 4. If you delete one of those categories, you need to remember to manually remove this id from `categories` array of user (with use of some `hook` or other tool), otherwise this user will still be assigned to a category that no longer exists.

```js
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    categories: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER)
}, {
    instanceMethods: {
        getCategories: function(){
            return Category.findAll({
                where: {
                    id: { $in: this.get('categories') }
                }
            }).then(categories => {
                // if user's categories was [1, 2, 4]
                // it would return categories with id=1, id=2 and id=4
                return categories;
            });
        },
        setCategories: function(ids){
            return this.setDataValues('categories', ids).save().then(self => {
                return self;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. A question, however: should it not be `this.setDataValue()`? *_notice the use of a singular form_

Comment: where is that `this` come from?

Comment: @AlanYong I guess it's from Model class

Answer (score 22):

To get sequelize query result with where condition for given array with using `**Op.in**` code to find result with in array as

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var Op = Sequelize.Op;
var arrayofTaskId = ['123', '456', '789'];
Tasks.findAll({
  where: {
    task_id: {
      [Op.in]: arrayofTaskId
    }
  }
}).then(function(result) {
  return res.json(result)
});
```