# How can I select based an array type property of a sequelize model?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a getAll query that returns

```
[ { id: 1,
    title: 'Fill me in',
    assignees:
     [ 'abc@gmail.com',
       'curioscat54@gmail.com',
       'davidol@gmail.com' ],
    is_completed: null,
    userId: 1,
    created_by: 'don gee',
    createdAt: 2020-05-06T10:49:32.712Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-05-06T10:49:32.712Z },
  { id: 2,
    title: 'Fill me in',
    assignees:
     [ 'qed@gmail.com',
       'curioscat54@gmail.com',
       'orekbajk@gmail.com' ],
    is_completed: null,
    userId: 1,
    created_by: 'don gee',
    createdAt: 2020-05-06T10:52:53.438Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-05-06T10:52:53.438Z } ]
```

Assignees is an array datatype. How can I specify a where clause to return only results where assignees equal a particular email for example where assignees = 'abc@gmail.com'?

So it should only return instances where assignees has 'abc@gmail.com' in it.

```
[ { id: 1,
    title: 'Fill me in',
    assignees:
     [ 'abc@gmail.com',
       'curioscat54@gmail.com',
       'davidol@gmail.com' ],
    is_completed: null,
    userId: 1,
    created_by: 'don gee',
    createdAt: 2020-05-06T10:49:32.712Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-05-06T10:49:32.712Z },
   ]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
async getAll(req, res){
    let val;
    try{
    val = await model.Matter.findAll({ 
        where: { 
            assignees:{
                [sequelize.Op.in]: ['curioscat54@gmail.com']
        }
    }
}); 
    return res.status(200).json({
        val
    });
} catch(err){
    return res.status(500).json({
        err:err.message
    })
}
}
```

But I get this error `values.map is not a function`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequelize relation with WHERE IN ("ARRAY")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719750/sequelize-relation-with-where-in-array)

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes  No it doesnt't yet. I have updated the question to reflect what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by changing `sequelize.Op.in` to `sequelize.Op.contains`

```
async getAll(req, res){
    let val;
    try{
    val = await model.Matter.findAll({ 
        where: { 
            assignees:{
                [sequelize.Op.contains]: ['curioscat54@gmail.com']
        }
    }
}); 
    return res.status(200).json({
        val
    });
} catch(err){
    return res.status(500).json({
        err:err.message
    })
}
}
```