# How to define an association to a model with array of foreign keys using sequelize with postgres

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, mongoose, sequelize.js

I have two models using mongoose as shown below:

1. Teams

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var teamsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    Description: {
        type: String

    },
    Is_Active: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Y", "N"],
        default: 'Y'
    }
}, { timestamps: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model('teams', teamsSchema);
```

2. Users

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    First_Name: {
        type: String
    },
    Last_Name: {
        type: String
    },
    Email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    Teams: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'teams' }],
    Is_Active: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Y", "N"],
        default: 'Y'
    }
}, { timestamps: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model('users', usersSchema);
```

We would like to migrate from MongoDB to PostgreSQL and we are using sequelize and created models as below

1. Teams

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class teams extends Model {
    
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  teams.init({
    Name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    Description: DataTypes.STRING,
    Is_Active: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['Y', 'N'],
      defaultValue: 'Y'
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'teams',
  });
  return teams;
};
```

2. Users

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class users extends Model {
    
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  users.init({
    First_Name: DataTypes.STRING,
    Last_Name: DataTypes.STRING,
    Email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    Teams: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER)
    },
    Is_Active: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['Y', 'N'],
      defaultValue: 'Y'
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'users',
  });
  return users;
};
```

With mongoose, we could able to get the **User** details along with **Teams** and **Teams** along with **Users**. How to associate a model in sequelize with an array of keys? How to write queries(find/join) in Sequelize with an array of foreign keys.

Once this is resolved, we need to think of nested arrays.

Comment: Can someone help me, to achieve the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719750/sequelize-relation-with-where-in-array. 
 using sequelize 6.3 with PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

Defining associations between models are very simple, as you can find it [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html).

I can see that you already have the `associate` method in each model.
You should add this in each method in order to have the correct associations:

1. Teams

```js
this.belongsToMany(models.users, { through: 'TeamUsers' });
```

2. Users

```js
this.belongsToMany(models.teams, { through: 'TeamUsers' });
```

Also, you don't need the `Teams` property in the Users model, since many-to-many associations exploit an external table in relational databases.

Here is an example of how to include users when querying for teams:

```js
models.teams.find({
  include: models.users
}).then(foundTeamsWithUsers => {
  // Handle here your teams: use users to access the list of users related to each team
}).catch(handleErrorFunction);
```

You can find more examples [about eager loading with sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I agree with you when it is M:M relation.  But, we would like to use **an array** for **Teams** in **Users** model since we have a few more tables like this scenario. Is it a good practice to have an array with foreign keys?

Comment: I think you could use an array, but I wouldn't consider it a good practice. But I'm not an expert on PostgreSQL, I've used Sequelize with MySQL, so I might be wrong on this. Also, I don't know how to include external tables that are not referenced with a relation like this using Sequelize without using raw SQL.